# HTML do not load CSS file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I started to develop a web page project with nodejs ejs engine.
It’s my git repo link: https://github.com/FikretAKBAS/teknikhane.git
The problem is when I start my project “npm start” html pages are loading but css file does not load. I tried many different things to figure out that but I didn’t get any solutions for that. In addition to I guess that’s a file path problem. I hope someone could help to solve this problem. Thanks a lot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r76xV.jpg)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: What is `assets` I don't see any folder named like this, but you are using it within paths

Answer (score 2):

Remove `/public` from your css files path 
for example 
before

```
  <!-- Additional CSS Files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/fontawesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/templatemo-edu-meeting.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/owl.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/lightbox.css">
```

after

```
  <!-- Additional CSS Files -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fontawesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/templatemo-edu-meeting.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/owl.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lightbox.css">
```

After you started the server 
Your public folder become a root folder for localhost:5000